# Unable to locate package shred. Meaning, apt-get can't find it and neither can I using Google

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, unix

I have come to depend on this unix utility to wipe SSD drives dependably and quickly in preparation for re-imaging.

I am curious as to why it is gone.

But the purpose of this question is to either:

1. Find a way to continue using it (on a USB-bootable unix installation to wipe the native SSD drive)
2. Find a suitable alternative

Comment: Why would you not use Secure Erase instead?

Comment: Shred is (or was?) a component of the Gnu CoreUtils package in Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks @kreemoweet, found it on github: https://github.com/wertarbyte/coreutils/blob/master/src/shred.c

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://superuser.com/users/26316/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) 
[ATA Secure Erase](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42266/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-empty-a-ssd) looks like the answer here.

Apparently while I was busy doing other things, ATA Secure Erase came on the scene and shred fell into obscurity.  Took me more time to type the commands for ATA Secure Erase than to actually execute them and wipe my 238G SSD.

The second best answer I came up with is:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda
```

Easy to type and dd is built in, but I gave up timing the execution after an hour had passed.